# Mobile javascript - read and write from/to text file

Tags: javascript, android, file, mobile, webview

I making application on mobile with HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT (using webview).
I need to read and write a local text file (e.g., file: ///android_asset/data/data.txt).
I was testing more options but not working.
It is possible?

My MainActivity.java file:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);

                WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

                WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

                webview.requestFocusFromTouch();

                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: more options but not working? what is that explain

Comment: Is any other solution this problem? E.g. set variable in Javascript after call android Java function (variable will has text from text file)?